# negative value input in while loop c++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have this code:

```
double i;
while(cin >> i)
{
    if ( i < 0.0)
        cout << "ENTER A POSITIVE NUMBER: ";
    else
        break;
}
```

I want code like this ( I don't want to use break):

```
while((cin >> i) < 0.0)
{
    cout << "ENTER A POSITIVE NUMBER: ";
}
```

I get an error on this line: `while((cin >> i) < 0.0)` saying `invalid operands to binary expression`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `(cin >> i)` does not return a double.

You can write the same statement, without a `break`, as:

```
double i;
while ((cin >> i) && (i < 0.0)) {
    cout << "ENTER A POSITIVE NUMBER: "; 
}
```

Comment: It does not return boolean.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: Reverting the `-1` as the code is correct. You might want to revisit the explanation, as `cin >> i` does not yield a boolean value, but a reference to the stream (which can be then converted to a `bool`)

Comment: This is all good, simple practice for you guys.  It was all about my oversight regarding the while and boolean.

Answer (score 10):

Use it like this.

```
while ((cin >> i) && (i < 0.0))
```

The overloaded function for `cin` returns an object by reference of `istream class`. So you cannot compare it to a double value.

```
cin >> i
|-------| //this is an object of istream class
```

Comment: +1, it is important to note that `&&` is a sequence point (old C++03 parlance) and thus it is guaranteed that `(i<0.0)` will only be evaluated after `cin >> i`.

Comment: This was it; I overlooked that fact that while does a bool check.  Makes total sense.

Answer (score 4):

you want to check the value of i, not the return of cin

```
while((cin >> i) && ( i < 0.0))
{
    cout << "ENTER A POSITIVE NUMBER: ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `cin >> i` is the stream, not the read value. This is to allow chaining of operands

```
cin >> i >> j;
```

<s>You could try this:</s>

```
while( (cin >> i, i) < 0. )
{
    cout << "ENTER A POSITIVE NUMBER: ";
}
```

The comma operator should return the value of `i` but I haven't tested it.

EDIT: Don't use this approach, as David Rodríguez has noted this discards the result of the read. Use `while( (cin >>i) && (i<0.) )` instead.

Comment: -1 The problem with this approach is that it completely ignores the result of the read. Say that `i` is negative and the user closes the input stream (or types a letter which fails to parse as a `double` and sets the `fail` bit in the stream), then the subsequent reads will fail, and the value of `i` will not be updated being still positive in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, I used the while((cin >> i) && (i < 0))

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
while( cin >> i && i < 0.0 )
{
    cout << "ENTER A POSITIVE NUMBER: ";
}
```

The error is caused due to the fact that the expression `(cin >> i)` is not valid for comparison with a double.

Comment: It's been a while since I've played with `operator,`; are you guaranteed that `cin >> i` is run before the `i < 0.0` when the thing on the left of the comma is an object?

Comment: Same issue as with `Alex`. The comma operator discards the first expression. If the input is `-1 a` you run into an infinite loop. In the first iteration `i` is set to `-1`, after that the read fails, `i` is unmodified and you enter an infinite loop.

Comment: @MaxLybbert: Yes, that is guaranteed by the standard, but this answer has other issues.